# Synchronize multiple axes over not visible attribute

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

### The situation

Suppose I have coordinates of positions at certain times. Let's say that data would look like

```
data = A[rand(100, 3), sort(rand(100, 1))]
```

where `data(:,1)` are the x-coordinates, `data(:,2)` the y-coordinates, `data(:,3)` the height and `data(:,4)` the time of recording.

I could easily plot that data using

```
pxy = subplot(2,2,1)            % Plot for X-Y-Data
plot(data(:,1), data(:,2))
ptx = subplot(2,2,2)            % Plot for T-X-Data
plot(data(:,4), data(:,1))
pty = subplot(2,2,3)            % ... and so on
plot(data(:,4), data(:,2))
pth = subplot(2,2,4)
plot(data(:,4), data(:,3))
```

Now, for viewing the figures, it would be great to synchronize the axes.

### First thoughts on possibilities

A trivial approach could be using `linkaxes` for the time-axis like

```
linkaxes([ptx, pty, pth], 'x')
```

However, this leaves the xy-plot unchanged. So, the weaker question would be how to link the y-axis of `ptx` to the x-axis of `pxy`.

But let's get even more complicated:

### The actual question

Suppose I only had two plots, `pxy` and `pth`. Now it would be great that whenever I zoom or pan in `pxy` the timespan visible in `pxy` is extracted and `pth` modified accordingly. Similarly, zooming `pth` alters `pxy` in a way that only the data in the correct time span is visible.

This approach should be scaleable in a way that I may plot an arbitrary subset of the 4 possible plots and linkage is done accordingly.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

An optimal solution still allows modifying that base plots by adding further data using `hold on`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (theoretical) problem with what you want, is that pxy should be invertible, and in the discrete domain (matlab is discrete), this becomes even less clear.

Suppose you have two points P1=(x1,y1) and P2=(x2,y2) which are near each other in pxy; to which axes-window on pth would you want the axes-window of pxy to correspond to if both P1 and P2 are visible in pxy? Pth1 or Pth2? You have to define some decision rules for this.. perhaps based on which of the two (P1 or P2) you actually click on.

Practically you have to run functions to change the axes when the user changes the zoom on pxy, this can be done as explained here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/21627-triggering-changes-in-plot-with-zoom-function

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am looking into the techniques you pointed me to right now. Feedback will be given as soon as possible.

Comment: Concerning the more theoretical issues: My approach would have been to use the following algorithm: Determine all data points P_i that are visible in `pxy` and compute min(P_i(t)) as well as max(P_i(t)). That will be the x-axis-limits of `pth`. That approach will certainly not always return best results, however, the nature of my data suggests that in most interesting cases that should be enough.

Comment: if your data is monotonically, it will be quite easy to invert. Hence your approach will also be accurate. You can think of many cases that would work, and also many that wouldn't..

Answer (score 1):

As a result of Gunthers hint I was able to solve the problem myself. 
As Gunthers answer still required quite a lot of research, I provide my own solution below, just in case somebody at some time will be stumbling on a similar problem.

First, I added most of the data needed as UserData in the axis-object. My plot function (for only two plots) looks roughly like this:

```
sb1 = subplot(1, 2, 1);
plot(data(:,1), data(:,2));
axis equal;
sb2 = subplot(1, 2, 2);
plot(data(:,4), data(:,3));
set(sb1, 'UserData', struct('projection', 'xy', 'data', data, 'link', [sb2]));
set(sb2, 'UserData', struct('projection', 'th', 'data', data, 'link', [sb1]));
panzoom(sb1, 'setlimits');   % Those two lines ensure that the zoom limits won't get changed
panzoom(sb2, 'setlimits');   % over time.
```

Now, I set the handler to my zoom function:

```
z = zoom;
set(z, 'ActionPostCallback', @Track.synchronizePlots);
z = pan;
set(z, 'ActionPostCallback', @Track.synchronizePlots);
```

And finally, this is the place where the magic happens:

```
function synchronizePlots(obj, ax)
    ax = ax.Axes;           
    ud = get(ax, 'UserData');

    if ud.projection == 'xy'
        % That is the part discussed in the comments above,
        % which is, as I freely admit, not very sensible on a strict
        % mathematical point of view. However, the result is good enough for my
        % purpose
        xrange = get(ax, 'XLim');
        yrange = get(ax, 'YLim');
        pointsvisible = ud.data(1,:) >= xrange(1) & ...
                        ud.data(1,:) <= xrange(2) & ...
                        ud.data(2,:) >= yrange(1) & ...
                        ud.data(2,:) <= yrange(2);
        r = [min(ud.data(4, pointsvisible)), max(ud.data(4, pointsvisible))];
        if length(r) == 0  % The trick above may fail if there is no point in the zoom region.
            return         % in that case we just do nothing.
        end
    else
        r = get(ax, 'XLim');  % Straightforward
    end


    for a = ud.link  % The function does not care about the number of figures that have to be changed.
        linkud = get(a, 'UserData');

        if linkud.projection == 'xy'
            % Again, changing the xy-plot is that only part we have to work.
            pointsintime = linkud.data(4,:) >= r(1) & ...
                           linkud.data(4,:) <= r(2);
            xrange = [min(linkud.data(1, pointsintime)), ...
                      max(linkud.data(1, pointsintime))];
            yrange = [min(linkud.data(2, pointsintime)), ...
                      max(linkud.data(2, pointsintime))];
            if length(xrange) > 0
                 set(a, 'XLim', xrange);
                 set(a, 'YLim', yrange);
                 axis(a, 'equal');
            end
        else
            set(a, 'XLim', r);
        end
    end
```

Hope that helps somebody.